# jquery script not working in bootstrap modal window

Tags: jquery, function, bootstrap-modal

Jquery fuction code is running in normal php pages but its not working inside bootstrap modal window...Plz. Help me??
 `

Answer (score -1):

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on("click", "#send-email", function(e) {
    alert('works');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

$(document).click() instead of $(document).on(). because, **on** will work newly added content. But **click** will not work newly added content.

refer: http://api.jquery.com/on/